# Event binding not working on div

Tags: html, jquery

I have a structure like this:

```
<ul id="container">
    <li>
        <div tabindex="1" class="selectThis">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span class="textToEdit" contenteditable="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Where it works to bind an event to the contenteditable span:

```
$("#container").on("keydown", ".textToEdit", function (e) {
    alert("yes");
});
```

But the div itself doesn't react:

```
$("#container").on("keydown", ".selectThis", function () {
    alert("no");
});
```

Using `.on` because the whole thing is dynamically generated, besides the container. I'm using jquery UI's `sortable` on said container. What is wrong with the binding? I've tried giving the `ul` and `li` a tabindex too, but the div still won't give me an alert.

Comment: is `container` dynamic too? If yes, use something else which is not dynamic.. or `$("document").on("keydown", ".textToEdit", function (e) {`

Comment: I tried it with [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/YwRUE/) and **no** popped up when hitting tab. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz Nope, you're right in that it indeed does work there. I'll try to see what I'm missing that makes it not work in my version and fix my post.

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz Ahh, got it--I'm using jquery UI's `sortable`, and that kills off the event: http://jsfiddle.net/YwRUE/1/

Comment: glad you found the error - keep on coding!

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz Unforunately I don't know how to fix it and thus am less glad

Comment: even within your jsfiddle example i still get **no** popping up when hitting the tab key!

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz !! Maybe the focus went to the editable span? It definitely doesn't work for me--a bit cleaner to test if the span is deleted I guess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40596/discussion-between-pilgerstorfer-franz-and-idlackage)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the div wasn't being focused after `sortable` is called on the `ul`--manually calling `$(".selectThis").focus()` makes it work. Thanks to [Pilgerstorfer Franz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476702/pilgerstorfer-franz) for making me aware of this!